# Finding observation percentile realtive to a distribution with purrr - R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to create a dplyr pipe that compares a value to a distribution and returns what percentile that value is relative to that distribution. Say I have this `tibble` with list-columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_val <- c(75,66, 80, 92, 91)

aq_nest <- airquality %>%
  select(Temp, Month) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  nest(Temp) %>%
  mutate(raw_val = raw_val)

> aq_nest
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Month              data raw_val
  <int>            <list>   <dbl>
1     5 <tibble [31 x 1]>      75
2     6 <tibble [30 x 1]>      66
3     7 <tibble [31 x 1]>      80
4     8 <tibble [31 x 1]>      92
5     9 <tibble [30 x 1]>      91
```

Now I can find what I want for a single `Month` value:

```
> ecdf(aq_nest$data[[1]]$Temp)(raw_val[1])
[1] 0.9032258
```

So that is 75 sits at about the 90th percentile.

But with `purrr` I feel like there must be a way to do this for each `Month` and add the result to the `aq_nest` tibble above. Here is what I've tried:

```
aq_nest <- airquality %>%
  select(Temp, Month) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  nest(Temp) %>%
  mutate(raw_val = raw_val) %>%
  mutate(Percentile = map2(data, raw_val, ~ecdf(.x)(.y)))
```

Which results in this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing.
```

So this betrays my lack of understanding with `purrr`. This `aq_nest$data[[1]]$Temp` is the first element of the list-column and returns a vector of integers. But when I try to `map` it I can't seem to figure out how to coerce it into that raw integer distribution so that `ecdf` will work.

To summarise, how can I use `purrr` and `ecdf` together so that it returns a vector a percentiles (i.e. comparing `raw_val` to `airquality$Temp` by `airquality$Month`?

Comment: You need to get the `ecdf` of `data$Temp`. Try `map2_dbl(data, raw_val, ~ecdf(.x$Temp)(.y))`

Comment: @aosmith This worked exactly. If you would like to do up as an answer I'll answer. Was almost there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass the `Temp` column to `ecdf` instead of the whole dataset.  Also if you use `map2_dbl` instead of `map2` you can get a non-list column as output.

In `mutate` you could use:

`map2_dbl(data, raw_val, ~ecdf(.x$Temp)(.y))`